# Ways to keep enable backward compatibility in a Python Library

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import sys

# This code exists for backwards compatibility reasons.
# I don't like it either. Just look the other way. :)

for package in ('urllib3', 'idna', 'chardet'):
  locals()[package] = __import__(package)
  # This traversal is apparently necessary such that the identities are
  # preserved (requests.packages.urllib3.* is urllib3.*)
  for mod in list(sys.modules):
    if mod == package or mod.startswith(package + '.'):
      sys.modules['requests.packages.' + mod] = sys.modules[mod]

# Kinda cool, though, right?
```

Source of this code is
[requests/packages.py](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/packages.py)

Docs of the same 
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

How does this help in enabling the backward compatibility of this python library?

Answer (score 1):

Compatibility hacks are often intricate, but they don't need to carry some timeless value. But, what could have happened here?

These 3 modules are external libraries:

- https://pypi.org/project/idna/
- https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/
- https://pypi.org/project/chardet/

Now I imagine originally they could have been bundled with `requests` in the `packages` folder instead of just being dependencies to install in `setup.py` of this library.

Now, it seems, they've fixed this, but there can be some code out there, which does `import requests.packages.urllib3` or something like that.

It may be still somewhere in their codebase (which they could just clean up), but maybe some of their users started treat them as `idna` / `urllib3` / `chardet` "providers", and their applications use requests together with these libraries and for this code to still work after the refactor, this trick is made.

What it technically does is add 'aliases' in `sys.modules` so that it points to the external modules.